# Alias setup -bash: vm: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, laravel, ssh, terminal

In the *Build Larabook from scratch* Laracast tutorial, it is required to synchronize the local folder of the app with the virtual machine (Homestead) and vice versa.

To simplify development, the tutorial recommends to create the following alias:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

by placing `alias vm="ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222"` in an `~/.aliases` file, which I did.

This lets the narrator simply type the `vm` command from the local app folder to launch the virtual machine.

When I try to do so, I get `-bash: vm: command not found`

Did I miss something?

Comment: What does the title "connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused" have to do with a question about setting up an alias?

Comment: @Kenster: this was a message error I had at one point. Just updated the question title. Thanks for your comment.